# Quantum Internal Efficiency

Tags: organic-chemistry, semiconductors

I'm reviewing a homework problem where we're given a hypothetical organic semiconductor which has a fluorescence efficiency of $40$% and a phosphorescence efficiency of $60$%.

From theory, I know that, the internal quantum efficiency is given by: $$\large\eta\small_{EL}=\large\eta\small_{PL}\cdot\large r_{st}\cdot\gamma_{cap}$$

where $\large\eta\small_{PL}$ is the photoluminescence efficiency, $r_{st}$ is the fraction of singlets over the total number of excitons formed and $\gamma_{cap}$ is the exciton formation number.

We assume that that simple spin-statistics arguments are valid to calculate the fraction of singlets or triplets generated by electron-hole mutual capture, and that the hole-electron capture efficiency is one.
I need to calculate the quantum internal efficiency of this diode with the additional assumption that intersystem crossing is negligible.  I am not sure where to start.

Comment: If intersystem crossing is not possible it means that once singlets and triplets are formed  they do not interconvert to form the other species.